# Как собрать все файлы js в один на gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Хочу собрать мои скрипты и подключаемые библиотеки в один js файл с помощью gulp. Подскажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй **gulp-concat** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)

Пример использования:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*.js') // путь к папке со скриптами
   .pipe(concat('all.js')) // в какой файл объединить
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

По ссылке, которую указал, есть больше примеров.

Comment: Еееее! Спасибо!